# Set server-side error in redux-form

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-form

I want to set server-side error in redux form `Field`. I am trying this:

```
<FormContatiner>
    <Field
        icon={ 'user' }
        returnKeyType={ 'next' }
        withRef
        ref={ (componentRef) => this.firstName = componentRef }
        refField="firstName"
        onEnter={() => {
            this.lastName.getRenderedComponent().refs.lastName.focus()
        }}
        placeholder={ consText.FIRST_NAME }
        component={ RenderInput }
        name={'first_name'}
    />

    <Field
        icon={ 'user' }
        returnKeyType={ 'next' }
        withRef
        ref={ (componentRef) => this.lastName = componentRef }
        refField="lastName"
        onEnter={() => {
            this.userName.getRenderedComponent().refs.userName.focus()
        }}
        placeholder={ consText.LAST_NAME }
        component={ RenderInput }
        name={ 'last_name' }
    />

    <Field
        icon={ 'user' }
        returnKeyType={ 'next' }
        withRef
        ref={ (componentRef) => this.userName = componentRef }
        refField={ 'userName' }
        onEnter={() => {
            this.email.getRenderedComponent().refs.email.focus()
        }}
        placeholder={ consText.USERNAME }
        component={ RenderInput }
        name={ 'username' }
        validate={ [] }
    />
</FormContatiner>
```

This function is called when I click on submit button:

```
onSubmit = (values) => {
    console.log(values);
    this.props.register(values,this.props.navigation);  
}
```

And this is the `this.props.register` function:

```
export const register = (user, navigation) => {

    return async (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type: REGISTER_REQUEST
        })
        try {
            await axios.post(URL + 'rest_users', user)
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    if(response.data.error==true) {
                         dispatch({
                            type: REGISTER_FAILER,
                            payload: response.data.errorMsg
                         });
                         throw new SubmissionError({ 
                             username: response.data.errorMsg.username[0],
                             _error: 'Login failed!'
                         });
                     }
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };
};
```

I'm getting this error:

> SubmissionError {errors: {…}, message: "Submit Validation Failed",
>   name: "SubmissionError", stack: "SubmissionError: Submit Validation
>   Failed↵ at h…rs\node_modules\expo\tools\hashAssetFiles:6502:9)"}

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: getting this error

SubmissionError {errors: {…}, message: "Submit Validation Failed", name: "SubmissionError", stack: "SubmissionError: Submit Validation Failed↵    at h…rs\node_modules\expo\tools\hashAssetFiles:6502:9)"}

Comment: i am following this link https://redux-form.com/6.4.3/examples/submitvalidation/  but i am stuck i don't know where i am going wrong

Comment: You are getting an error because you are throwing SubmissionError

Comment: yes i have got username already exits error and i want to show this error on username Field

Comment: Can you show more code? This one looks fine.

Comment: ` <Field
                  icon={'user'}
                  returnKeyType={'next'}
                  withRef
                  ref={(componentRef) => this.userName = componentRef}
                  refField={'userName'}
                  onEnter={() => {
                    this.email.getRenderedComponent().refs.email.focus()
                  }}
                  placeholder={consText.USERNAME}
                  component={RenderInput}
                  name={'username'}
                  validate={[]}
                />`

Comment: Please, edit your question.

Comment: on button click
<code>
export const register = (user, navigation) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {  
    try {
      await axios.post(URL + 'rest_users', user)
        .then(function (response) {
          //navigation.navigate('');
          console.log(response);
          if(response.data.error==true){
            dispatch({
              type: REGISTER_FAILER,
              payload: response.data.errorMsg
            });
            throw new SubmissionError({ username: response.data.errorMsg.username[0] ,_error: 'Login failed!'});

        }
        });

</code>

Comment: i have edited my code please have a look and suggest me your answer

Comment: If you use `async/await` you don't need the `then` function, just get the result returned.

Comment: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):
[SubmissionError: Submit Validation Failed]

getting this warning